# Adding module dependency after using NDK in android studio

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

i am creating an AAR Library to be distributed which contains openCV in C++.
once i try to create the module and try to add dependency to the app the module cannot be "Seen" and give me an error.

i followed the tutorials on how to create a module but i think i am missing something specially that i am using NDK and gradle experimental.

in my Build.gradle file for the project i used the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.1'  
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

in my build.gradle (Module app) i used the following

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.example.app"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 21
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.pro'))
            }
        }
    }
}    

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile project(':mylib')
}
```

in the module i used the following to be able to use OpenCV

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 25
        buildToolsVersion = "25.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 21
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.pro'))
            }
        }

        ndk {

            moduleName = "myclib"
            cppFlags.addAll(["-std=c++11", "-fexceptions", "-frtti"])
            cppFlags.add("-I" + file("src/main/jni").absolutePath)
            ldLibs.addAll(["android", "EGL", "GLESv2", "dl", "log", "z"])
            stl = "gnustl_static"
        }

        productFlavors {
            create("arm") {
                ndk.with {
                    abiFilters.add("armeabi")
                    File curDir = file('./')
                    curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                    String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/"
                    ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")
                }
            }

            create("armv7") {
                ndk.with {
                    abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
                    File curDir = file('./')
                    curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                    String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/"
                    ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")
                }
            }
            create("x86") {
                ndk.with {
                    abiFilters.add("x86")

                    File curDir = file('./')
                    curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                    String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "/src/main/jniLibs/x86/"
                    ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")
                }
            }  
             create("mips") {
               ndk.with {
               abiFilters.add("mips")

               File curDir = file('./')
               curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
               String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "/src/main/jniLibs/mips/"

                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")
            }
        }
        create("fat") {

        }
    }

}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
}
```

i try calling an activity in the module from the app but it give me cannot find the package and ask me to add dependency for the module.
i did that yet still same error and on build.gradle i find that i have

```
compile project(':mylib')
```

added as many times as i try to add the dependency.

what have i done wrong and how to solve this issue

Comment: I had a similar issue, If you open Build Variants you will see a list of modules. Click on the info button of the app module, here you should see a connection from your library to your app. Can you see this or do you only see the app module with no connection?

Comment: the app has no connections to the module. i dont know if this might help, but i have for the app both the debug and releas while for the module i have for each flavor that is there a debug and a realease and none of those are connected

Comment: It seems you have the same issue that i have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869924/gradle-experimental-android-library-module-dependency-not-executed. Unfortunately I do not have a solution for this but my workaround was to remove the product flavors from the lib module.

Comment: hi Alex thank you for the reply. can i remove the product flavors if i am using native opencv? and can you help me with the build.gradle how it should be if i remove flavors for opencv? thanks

Comment: You should take a look at this: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-NDK-Dependencies They describe how you can link brebuilt libraries.